# jQuery printElement not printing whole image

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, base64

I'm using [printElement](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) to print a base64 encoded image (1000 x 5883).

Everything is OK apart from it will only print one page when the image itself is about 4/5 pages long.

Not sure if it's because my image is base64 encoded or if i'm using the [printElement](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) function incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
<a id="print" style="cursor:pointer">Print</a>
<img src="bluemoon.jpg" id="tes" align="middle"  class="b" width="100%"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#print').click(function(){
    $('#tes').printElement(
        {
            printBodyOptions:
            {
                styleToAdd:'padding:10px;margin:10px;color:#FFFFFF !important;width:100%!important;',
                classNameToAdd : 'b',
                leaveOpen:true
            }
        });
    })

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using this code.

```
$('#result').css('display', 'block');
$('#result').printElement({ printMode: 'popup' });
$('#result').css('display', 'none');
```

toggling the visibility made the print work correctly ! Now it is printing the whole picture.
Enjoy :)